# How to use multiprocessing apply_async pool in a while loop correctly

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pool

I need to use a pool to asynchronously parse results coming from an extraction method and send those results to a write queue.

I have tried this: but it seems to just run iteratively... one process after the other.

```
process_pool = Pool(processes=30, maxtasksperchild=1)
while True:
    filepath = read_queue.get(True)
    if filepath is None:
        break
    res = process_pool.apply_async(func=process.run, args=(filepath, final_path), callback=write_queue.put)
    results.append(res)
    for result in results:
        result.wait()
process_pool.close()
process_pool.join()
```

I have also tried just waiting on each result, but that does the same thing as the above:

```
process_pool = Pool(processes=30, maxtasksperchild=1)
while True:
    filepath = read_queue.get(True)
    if filepath is None:
        break
    res = process_pool.apply_async(func=process.run, args=(filepath, final_path), callback=write_queue.put)
    res.wait()
process_pool.close()
process_pool.join()
```

I also tried just scheduling processes and letting the pool block itself if it's out of workers to spawn:

```
process_pool = Pool(processes=30, maxtasksperchild=1)
while True:
    filepath = read_queue.get(True)
    if filepath is None:
        break
    process_pool.apply_async(func=process.run, args=(filepath, final_path), callback=write_queue.put)
process_pool.close()
process_pool.join()
```

This doesn't work, and just runs through the processes over and over, not actually running any sort of function and I'm not sure why. It seems I have to do something with the `AsyncResult` for the pool to actually schedule the process.

I need it to work like this:

- When there is a result waiting in the queue, spawn a new process in the pool with that specific argument from the queue.
- On callback, put that processed result in the write queue.

However, I can't seem to get it to work asynchronously correctly. It will only work iteratively because I have to do something with result to actually get the task to schedule properly. Whether that is a `.get`, `.wait`, whatever.

```py
#  write.py
def write(p_list):
    outfile = Path('outfile.txt.bz2')
    for data in p_list:
        if Path.exists(outfile):
            mode = 'ab'
        else:
            mode = 'wb'
        with bz2.open(filename=outfile, mode=mode, compresslevel=9) as output:
            temp = (str(data) + '\n').encode('utf-8')
            output.write(temp)
    print('JSON files written', flush=True)


class Write(Process):
    def __init__(self, write_queue: Queue):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.write_queue = write_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                p_list = self.write_queue.get(True, 900)
            except Empty:
                continue
            if p_list is None:
                break
            write(p_list)

-

# process.py

def parse(data: int): 
    global json_list
    time.sleep(.1)   # simulate parsing the json
    json_list.append(data)


def read(data: int):
    time.sleep(.1)
    parse(data)


def run(data: int):
    global json_list
    json_list = []
    read(data)
    return json_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global output_path, json_list

-

# main.py

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_queue = Queue()
    write_queue = Queue()

    write = Write(write_queue=write_queue)

    write.daemon = True
    write.start()

    for i in range(0, 1000000):
    read_queue.put(i)
    read_queue.put(None)

    process_pool = Pool(processes=30, maxtasksperchild=1)

    while True:
        data = read_queue.get(True)
        if data is None:
            break
        res = process_pool.apply_async(func=process.run, args=(data,), callback=write_queue.put)

    write_queue.put(None)

    process_pool.close()
    process_pool.join()

    write.join()

    print('process done')
```

Comment: Your third example should be working. The fact that `process.run` never seems to execute at all is very strange. Can you make a complete reproducer that shows the problem? Your first example is running sequentially because you put the for-loop inside of the `while True:` loop. Move the for-loop after the while-loop and it should also work properly.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that i need this pool to create workers for thousands of files. I was originally using processes for this, but the processes were not returning memory to the OS so that's why you see `maxtaskperchild=1`. I will try putting the wait outside of the while loop

Comment: @dano I've added a proper reproducible example. I don't include all the methods of the reading and parsing, but it should be explanatory what happens with it. The extract method does nothing more than extract a certain amount of files to a directory and send those filepaths to `read_queue`

Comment: That example gives a little more detail, but I can't actually run it. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @dano I will try. Putting up something now. I don't know how I can exactly produce something like that because there needs to be files that can be read from for it to work, but maybe you can make some mock json files or download a collection to simulate.

Comment: I would recommend creating an example that doesn't require reading anything from a file at all. If your problem is really with `multiprocessing`, it should reproduce even if you feed it some small amount of dummy data, right?

Comment: Okay, how about now? It should work fine

Comment: Is `Queue` a multiprocessing Queue?

Comment: @dano Yes it is

Comment: Your example right now doesn't work because you set the read_queue maxsize at 30, but try to put 1000000 items in it, which blocks. If I fix that, it fails because the `process` in `process.run` is not defined.

Comment: Okay, I fixed a couple errors. Sorry about that

Comment: There are still several errors in this example: `(args)` should be `(args,)`, you never passed `None` to `read_queue`, so you never make it out of the `while True` loop in main.py, there's issues with `json_list`, `extract`, and  `outfile` not being defined properly, etc. Once I fixed all those, the script ran fine. I think you need to work on the example more.

Comment: Okay, but did you find any problems with the pool? I'll go ahead and update those.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is that there is no problem. I'm just stupid. If you define a max task per worker of 1, the processes will schedule very quickly and it will look like nothing is happening (or maybe im the only one who thought that).

Here's a reasonable way to use an asynchronous process pool correctly within a `while` loop with a `maxtasksperchild` of `1`

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def func(elem):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        return elem
    
    def callback(elem):
        # do something with processed data
        pass

    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        queue.put(i)

    process_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes, maxtasksperchild=1)

    results = []
    while True:
        data = queue.get(True)
        if data is None:
            break
        res = process_pool.apply_async(func=func, args=(data,), callback=callback)
        results.append(res)

    flag = False
    for i, res in enumerate(results):
        try:
            res.wait(600)
            # do some logging
            results[i] = None
        except TimeoutError:
            flag = True
            # do some logging

    process_pool.close()
    if flag:
        process_pool.terminate()
    process_pool.join()
    # done!
```

Comment: This is not true. As soon as you call `apply_async`, `process.run` will execute in a worker process. You don't have to wait for the result for it to start executing.

Comment: @dano I don't know what else it is then man. You've literally said the exact same thing, and I get that that's probably really how it is, but it plainly doesn't work in my case. It just constantly runs through and schedules worker processes over and over and never actually calls anything

Comment: Try fetching the actual result (with .get()) from the AsyncResult objects. The calls might be failing for some reason.

Comment: alright so it's just a complete misunderstanding on my part. you're right, the processes were being scheduled, but because i define a `max task per child` of `1`, it fills up the entire screen's logging output very quickly and made me think it wasn't actually processing anything